# Error message after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, usb-installation

Hello to all of you,

I have recently installed on my laptop Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. (Wayland) I originally wanted to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS in dual-boot with Windows 10, the original OS on my pc. However, during the installation process, Ubiquity, "announces" to my great surprise that there is no other OS currently installed on my PC! So I have no choice but to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS instead of Windows 10...
The installation went well and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS becomes my one and only OS on the PC.
However, every time I start my PC, an error message appears. Here it is almost in full:

1.1207611 firewire_ohci 0000:09:00.0: register access failure

I would like to point out that despite the appearance of this error message at the startup of the PC, I have never had any problems during my daily use of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Nevertheless, I would like to know more about the meaning of this error message.

So if someone could help me to know more about it, it would be really nice wink

Thanks in advance for your help and have a great day!

Comment: A few corrections and info are in order: 1. There are only few possible reasons for the installer not detecting Windows, Fast Startup enabled, incompatible dynamic disks or similar, or booting in as different mode (Legacy vs. UEFI). So no, you didn't have to replace Windows, a correct troubleshooting would have enabled the dual-boot. 2. The error is irrelevant and likely related with some UEFI quirkiness. Update it and it may or may not "fix", or a later kernel update may or may not take that into account.

Comment: Indeed, during the installation of Ubuntu with my USB key, I encountered a problem with the UEFI and I did not find in the BIOS how to disable the secure boot. I finally managed to install Ubuntu using Legacy.
Now I have Ubuntu 22.04 only. It works well except for a boot time that I find too long and difficulties to install and run some applications. (TOR for example)
Do you think I should update the UEFI? And if so, how? Should I wait for a possible update that would fix the problem or should I "just" reinstall Ubuntu?

Thanks a lot for your help! 
Have a nice day!